# Split text to columns from complex form submissions

Tags: google-sheets, split

The data from my form populated into a single cell rather than across columns and has content headers separating the data within that cell. I would like to separate the data by the data header. For example, the source data look like:

Site Name: Girls in Gear eight-week program, First Name: Alishia, Last Name: Pretlow,

and I'd like the Site Name, First Name, Last name, etc. to split into columns, ideally without the headers. The challenge I am facing that prevents me from using the simple comma is that there are fields where the text entered includes columns and is being split at each one creating a lot of data errors and necessary cleanup.

Any guidance on how to separate this data automatically is greatly appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PSAQYP-DBxB3Ybjy0qpt0lnpRpC6uYIedSVpR4dpZPo/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried using the split formula in several ways, including wrapping my data headers in ' ', separating data headers with the | and none are working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I put my answer in another tab, because a couple of headers had little typo errors on them so it wouldn't work as expected:

```
=BYCOL(B1:1,LAMBDA(header,LET(string,A2,
start,SEARCH(header,string)+LEN(header),
length,SEARCH(OFFSET(header,0,1),string)-start-2,
IFERROR(MID(string,start,length),MID(string,start,LEN(string)-start)))))
```

It finds the header and the next one and returns the value in between with MID. That IFERROR is meant to the last header which won't be able to return correctly since there's not another header after it

[image]

If you need it for several consecutive rows:

```
=MAP(TOCOL(A2:A,1),LAMBDA(answer,
BYCOL(B1:1,LAMBDA(header,LET(string,answer,
start,SEARCH(header,string)+LEN(header),
length,SEARCH(OFFSET(header,0,1),string)-start-2,
IFERROR(MID(string,start,length),MID(string,start,LEN(string)-start)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

*[Here's one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PSAQYP-DBxB3Ybjy0qpt0lnpRpC6uYIedSVpR4dpZPo/edit#gid=717775783) you may test out:*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,index(regexreplace(split(reduce(Σ,sequence(33),lambda(a,c,substitute(a,index(B1:AH1,,c),""))),""),"^ |, $",)))))
```

- *Please do make a note that column Headers in **K1** `Include in Program -Finder?:` and **V1** `Grades Served:` are altered to match with the same in single cell data*

[image]